# How do I access the response body(data) coming in from an ajax call in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

In all other browsers besides Internet Explorer I am able to access response data from an ajax request using the jQuery Form Plugin. When I do the same in Internet Explorer, the data comes in but I have no access to it. I keep receiving a "SCRIPT5: Access Denied" error in IE9's console. How do I access this data since it is clearly coming in but anytime I even try to console it throws that very error. And yes, console.log does work in IE9. I've tested it.

```
function run() {
        $("#testing").ajaxSubmit({
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var parsedjson = JSON.parse(data)[0];
            }
        });
    }

<form id="testing" action="http://clvapi/upload/uploadhandler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="twitter-bootstrap-upload">
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
      <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
      <div>
        <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="files[]" onchange="run()"/></span>
        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What version of jQuery core are you running?

Comment: @user1074316 Just so there's no ambiguity, do you mean version 1.8.3?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `testing` is your form.

Try this out instead of using the plugin:

```
    $("#testing").on('submit', function(){
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var parsedjson = JSON.parse(data)[0];
        });
        return false; //prevent the default `submit` from occuring
    });
```

Then  when you want to submit the form (programmatically) just do:

```
    $("#testing").trigger('submit');
```

Or if you do not want to submit the form from your js code, just submit it as you normally would do.

Comment: Don't forget to prevent the default submit action :)

Comment: If you don't, then the regular post will still occur and the page will reload.

Comment: @MichaelMior OOO thats what you are saying! did not notice that I forgot that lol. I added it ^_^ ( I thought you were asking me to add the second part )

Comment: hahaha. No worries. Although I'd suggest capturing the event parameter in the handler and using `preventDefault()` to avoid stopping event propagation if it's needed. It's also a bit more explicit. Probably just the same in this case though :)

Comment: @MichaelMior `return false;` does the same thing in this case, there is no real reason to use both....

Comment: so what's the best way to prevent the submit? or is it in the example above?

Comment: @user1074316 use my example.. there is no `best way`

Comment: another thing is that the input file is an image? will that matter?

Comment: @user1074316 you cannot use jQuery's native ajax function for file forms.

Comment: the input is a file type which is why i was using the plugin

Comment: @Neal `return false` and `preventDefault` aren't quite the same. `return false` will also prevent event bubbling. This isn't the case with `preventDefault`. I'm not suggesting both. I prefer using `preventDefault` in all cases. (And explicitly preventing propagation as well if needed.)